# Installing Boost port in MacPorts

Tags: xcode, macos, boost, port, macports

I just installed MacPorts and am trying to install the boost port.  When I type:

```
sudo port install boost
```

however, I get an error that says

```
Unable to open port: invalid command name "compiler.blacklist"
```

How can I fix this issue?  When I try to do the installation in Pallet instead, nothing happens after choosing install and pressing "start."

Thank you for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

You're running an outdated version of MacPorts. Run `sudo port selfupdate`. If that fails, you can try to get more information on the type of failure using `sudo port -d selfupdate`. If that doesn't help either you can just use the most recent installer from the MacPorts website to update your installation.